# Background image url is not showing the image

Tags: html, css, background

I have designed an html css theme. It is not running on any server or localhost. I kept the theme including all its css js files in one directory. Its path is D -> website -> theme.

In the html file I used several images. My html code for image is

```
 `<img src="images/share.png" class="image-gap">`
```

This code perfectly show image on the html page. I also need to show a background image and I used this html code

```
<div class="background-image-holder">
Only some text here. Background of this text should be a small image
<div>
```

CSS for above html

```
.background-image-holder{
   background-image: url('images/share.png');
}
```

Image perfectly show on html page but same image path and image do not show as background image. When I hover over the firebug css background-image it show this message

```
Failed to load the given url
```

how can I show this image as background image. And why my present approach is not working? BTW I found some questions on this website but answers are not working for me.

Comment: It should work. Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nicolaeolariu/j2LBL/).

Comment: css `url()` are relative to the location of the .css file, not the html file that's loading that css. e.g. if your file is `/index.html`, and it's loading `/css/styles.css`, then the background image is going to be searched for as `/css/images/share.png`.

Comment: @MarcB add your answer and I will accept it. You saved the day. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS `url()` are relative to the location of the .css file, not the html file that's loading that css. e.g. If your file is `/index.html`, and it's loading `/css/styles.css`, then the background image is going to be accessed as `/css/images/share.png`

Comment: life saver. I was on a deadline but all answers were same except you explained the right thing :)

Answer (score 0):

I think code should be like -

```
.background-image-holder{
   background-image: url('../images/share.png');
}
```